# Generating a PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, io, pdf-generation

I'm trying to write a PDF file in Java to say the words `hello neckbeards` but when I run my program, Adobe Reader opens but an error comes up saying:

```
There was an error opening this document.
The file is already open or in use by another application.
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;

public class count10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File tempfile = File.createTempFile("report", ".pdf");
        FileWriter pfile = new FileWriter(tempfile);
        pfile.write("hello neckbeards");

        Desktop dtop = null;

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            dtop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        }
        if (dtop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)){
            String path = tempfile.getPath();
            dtop.open(new File(path));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the a couple of people below have mentioned, iText is a great way to build pdf files.  Please review the license of iText prior to any major development.

Comment: Wow.  This wouldn't happen to be a homework assignment would it?

Comment: `@neckbeard69` **1)** If this is homework, please mark it with the `homework` tag. **2)** When you found an answer that _solves_ your problem, please **accept** it by checking its **green tick**, near the votes area. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are many errors here:

- You are writing **plain text**. Adobe Reader will throw an error as the file is not a valid PDF!
  To write PDFs, use libraries like [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com) or PDFBox.
- Before you can write or read a file, you  **open** a connection from your program to the file.
  So, when you end writing/reading the file, **don't forget to close the connection** so that other programs (such as Adobe Reader) can read the file too! To close the file, simply do:

  ```
  pfile.close();
  ```
- The `main` method shouldn't throw any exception. Instead, if an error occurs, it **must** be catched and do the appropiate actions (tell the user, exit, ...).
  To read/write files (or anything), this is the **recommended structure**:

  ```
  FileReader reader = null;
  try {
      reader = new FileReader("file.txt"); //open the file

      //read or write the file

  } catch (IOException ex) {
      //warn the user, log the error, ...
  } finally {
      if (reader != null) reader.close(); //always close the file when finished
  }
  ```
- The final `if` has a **bad** place. The correct code would be:

  ```
  if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
      Desktop dtop = Desktop.getDesktop();
      if (dtop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
          dtop.open(tempfile);
      }
  }
  ```

  Also, notice that I call the `open` method passing the file **directly**.
  There's no need to make a copy of it.

Answer (score 4):

To create a PDF file you can use a library such as [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/). It seems to me that you are simply creating a plain text file and then attempting to open it with a PDF reader.

Answer (score 4):

After you write to your file, you have to close it, using `pfile.close()`;

Note that what you wrote is just a text file with contents `hello neckbeards` and extension `.pdf`. It is **not** a PDF file in a normal sense that can be opened with a PDF reader like Adobe Reader.

Use a library like [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) to create real PDF files.

A file must follow the [PDF implementation](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (PDF file) to be a valid PDF file. As you can see, this is much more involved, than "just" writing text to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with opening files from the desktop in that way, but it's worth closing your FileWriter after writing the file.  Incidentally, I've found XSLT to be a good way of producing PDF documents, as you get a great deal of control over the output and ongoing maintenance and adjustments don't involve re-compiling your code (useful if you have a marketing department who like changing their minds).  Take a look at XSL-FO if you're interested, Apache FOP is a good implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this code....
    Document document=new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("E:/data.pdf"));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(2);
               table.addCell("Employee ID");
               table.addCell("Employee Name");
               table.addCell("1");
               table.addCell("Temperary Employee");
               document.add(table);
               document.close();

You have to import....
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```